# Find out which Active MQ is up?

Tags: java, spring, jms, activemq-classic

I am new to this ActiveMQ. I have this scenario where I have two ActiveMQ nodes, somewhat like this:

```
amq1.url=http://abcd01.xxxxxxxxxxx:8041/api/message/
amq2.url=http://abcd02.xxxxxxxxxxx:8041/api/message/
```

I want to find in my `@PostConstruct` method that which of these two nodes is up and running and use that URL for sending a message further.
I have already searched a lot about it and I don't want to use `ActiveMQConnectionFactory` here.
Is there a way to find the pingStatus of an ActiveMQ node?
Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of manually determining which ActiveMQ instance is up, use the [failover](http://activemq.apache.org/failover-transport-reference.html) transport. Something like this:

```
failover:(tcp://primary:8041,tcp://secondary:8041)?initialReconnectDelay=100
```

Comment: :Thank you for your reply, but I would be needing the URL i.e. 'amq01' or 'amq02' whichever is up and running. Requirement is to fetch the URL which is up amongst the two.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to access active mq mbeans using a jmx client ,like jconsole etc...if you are able to see  whole mbean library of an instance in the jmx console..tat indicates instance is up.
By default jmx service is enabled (at least in the version I am using 5.13.x)

Answer (score 0):

You can query the broker via Jolokia.

For a localhost broker (change name/host to match your config):

http://localhost:8161/api/jolokia/read/org.apache.activemq:type=Broker,brokerName=localhost

You will get a json back. Parse the `Value.Slave` response value. It will be `true` or `false`.

Basic Authentication is usually needed as well. So make sure pass that in the request.